# Spurious MissingMethodException, Grails 2.2.5

Tags: grails

I've suddenly started getting a MissingMethodException in my Grails 2.2.5 app, without any change in code and the error is seemingly spurious, so I'm suspecting corruption somewhere. I'm getting this error:

```
No signature of method: arthurs.Sale.findByCustomerAndComplete() is applicable for argument types: (arthurs.Customer, java.lang.Boolean) values: [arthurs.Customer : 59, false]
Possible solutions: findByCustomerAndComplete([Ljava.lang.Object;). Stacktrace follows:
Message: No signature of method: arthurs.Sale.findByCustomerAndComplete() is applicable for argument types: (arthurs.Customer, java.lang.Boolean) values: [arthurs.Customer : 59, false]
Possible solutions: findByCustomerAndComplete([Ljava.lang.Object;)
```

This worked fine until yesterday. The Sale class does in fact have 'customer' (Customer class) and 'complete' (Boolean) properties, and I've checked that what I'm passing are valid parameters. In any case, the error message does specify the argument types and these are correct.

So why might my dynamic 'findBy...' method suddenly stop working? In the past I've often found doing a 'grails clean' often sorts such things out but it doesn't seem to have helped with this one.

Is there something else I should clear out, to give myself a blank slate?

Answer (score 0):

Well, don't know what had happened there but deleting the project folder from '.grails/2.2.5/projects' did the trick.

LATER: No, the problem has returned. Very puzzled by this now.

LATER STILL: Well, I've now determined what it is that triggers the problem, although I am completely baffled as to why it does so. If I add a 'created' property of type Date to my Sale class, the problem recurs and remains until I remove the property, remove the column from the MySQL table, and delete the project folder. If, however, I mark this property as nullable in constraints, it works OK. ???

Comment: Did you try querying with where, criteria, or hql queries to see if you get a different behaver?

Comment: No I didn't. I was able to work around the issue when it first came up, with `def sale = customer.sales.find{it.complete==false}`, which does the same thing a different way. The point was, though, that there was nothing wrong with my code. I am uneasy about swapping out a bit of code which doesn't work when it should, I'd rather find the underlying problem elsewhere.